# Binding from DataSet to TextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml-binding

```
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=" + dbServer + ";" + "database=" + databaseNavn + ";" + "user id=" + dbUser + ";" + "pwd=" + dbPwd);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM VisualGolfAS.Customer.Name AS CustomerName;", myConnection);

        myDataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(myDataSet,"CustomerName");
        myTexttBox.DataContext = myDataSet;
        myTexttBox.Text =
```

How do i set the Text property based on the code above?

1. Programmatically
2. Via XAML

Comment: What information you want to bind to textbox ?

Comment: It is hard to know which data is given to your `myDataSet`. But roughly, you can try `<TextBox Text={Binding} />` in your XAML file.